# Delete Query to remove duplicates and keep the latest record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB and there-in is a table, lets say "aura"

[image]

Now in this table there are different records with duplicates. I have to remove these duplicates.

As you can see in the image above **Dsvsd**, **Cvra**, **Single Entry** & **Double Entry**

The logic for the removal of the duplicates is, The highest(biggest) `Review_ID` & If the record does not have duplicates like **Single Entry** keep it. Now I can not do this task manually because there record count of the table is 84,000 and there are 18,000 distinct records. **How to do it with a query?** OR **What is the best approach for this task**

This is the expected result

[image]

Comment: Why would `cvra` be 6 and not 10 in your sample data?  BTW -- one option is to use `row_number` to get highest, and then delete the others...

Comment: my bad... cvra should be `10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using `rowid` and the `row_number` ranking function to delete duplicates:

```
delete from auro
where  rowid in
( select rwid
  from ( select rowid rwid,
                row_number() over ( partition by name
                                    order by review_id desc) rn
         from   auro
       ) t
  where  rn>1
)
```

Comment: the only problem with this query is I have other checks on the other attributes
`delete from auro where  rowid in ( ********)  and blk is not null, kli is null, blk_rk is null`. These checks extra checks are not working...

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from aura where id not in (
select min(id) keep (dense_rank last order by review_id nulls first) 
from aura
group by name
)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this somewhere in your code(please ignore syntax error cause i am a noob in sql)
SELECT name AS n FROM auro HAVING count(name)>1
BEGIN
  LOOP
    SELECT MAX(review_id), MIN(review_id) AS maxid, minid FROM auro HAVING name=n
    DELETE FROM auro
    WHERE name=n;
    EXIT WHEN maxid=minid;
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: A more complete example of the DML you are proposing would be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

try this somewhere in your code(please ignore syntax error cause i am a noob in sql) SELECT name AS n FROM auro HAVING count(name)>1 BEGIN LOOP
SELECT MAX(review_id), MIN(review_id) AS maxid, minid FROM auro HAVING name=n DELETE FROM auro WHERE name=n; EXIT WHEN maxid=minid; END LOOP; END

Comment: Sorry for sending it twice suffering from network problems that's why previous answer was incomplete sorry once again